# Parallax scrolling on Material Design Lite not working?

Tags: html, css, web, material-design-lite

Parallax scrolling backgrounds don't seem to work on Material Design Lite. Or I'm doing it wrong.

This is my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd9yH.png

The huge whitespace in the middle is not showing the background-image or background: I'm giving it when testing it out on a HiDPI screen. However, it works on other screen sizes like MDPI and smaller ones (at least according to Chrome). I tried using a separate .parallax class with the following:

```
.parallax{
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

but that didn't work nor did it work with the code that's in the image.

I'm using the Material Design Lite framework and I think it's that that's causing the issue. When I go into the Inspect Element view and remove both display: flex and display: webkit-flex on the .mdl-layout class, it seems to work.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue with parallax and MDL, but using the React framework. Here, it seems, the parallax component didn't get bubble scroll events when used inside MDL components. Listening to capture scroll events resolved the issue for me. Doesn't sound like this is your problem, but perhaps worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 0):

paralax doesnt work due to problem with css overflow settings in MDL.

There are two ways of fixing it:
1. change overflow setting in MDL css
2. Map height of site/scroll on div with class `.mdl-layout__content`

for example for events on scroll:

```
  $('.mdl-layout__content').on('scroll', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out like below at material.css file.

```
.mdl-layout__container {
  /* position: absolute;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
```

This may cause non fixed header and drawer,
so we have to resolve this issue. :)